# Proper method of Client-side decoration in Qt5

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, qt5, custom-controls

I'm a fan of CSD  , and I want to use it via Qt5.Currently in linux just Gtk has implemented it properly with [GtkHeaderBar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html).

It has a nice and clean api which does all the complicated stuff behind picking the window decoration buttons , following the system theme and colors , etc. Even in DEs which are based on Qt like `KDE` , it does that well.

But I cannot find any clean framework to do so in Qt5 .Although somehow it's possible to [do that](https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations) , but at the end it's not theme-aware and also I got problems about moving the window via dragging the fake title-bar.

Does anybody have suggestions about how to do so with the tools currently present in Qt5?

Comment: It seems that in Qt 5.15 it will be officially supported: https://www.qt.io/blog/custom-window-decorations

Comment: @eyllanesc Yes , I know . I've tried that. But it still lacks some useful features like theme management.Just look at how macOS or Windows guys are implementing it. It is very seemless and matches other normal applications. In that example ,window buttons are just single characters !!!

Comment: It would be good if you report a bug pointing out the other missing features of the CSD so that in future Qt 5.15 or Qt6 they add it. (please avoid useless `!!!`)